# PHP - date() not safe? what do I use?

Tags: php, datetime, date

I get the following warning in my PHP error log:

> PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

So, what do I use instead of or with `date()`?

Comment: Why not just set a default time zone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still use `date`. What's not safe is ***to rely on the system's timezone settings.***

It says you should explicitly set your timezone in your script using [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set).

Answer (score 1):

What was unclear in the warning?

It is not safe **to rely on the system's timezone settings.**

Set the timezone in your config:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Riga");
```

..for example.

Answer (score 0):

You get it wrong:

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

There is no problem with `date()` at all, but you should not rely on what your system tells you. Just set your prefered default time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timezone before you use the date function. You are on the web which is "everywhere". So, you should respect the time your user is on (Japan or Mexico).

Or set a default timezone using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Queensland')
```